# Do a sum - group By in Sybase by a column that represents a period

Tags: sql, database, sybase

```
CREATE TABLE "DBA"."TIME_SPENT_DATA" (
  "id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "manual_number" INTEGER NULL,
  "user_id" INTEGER NULL,
  "session_id" VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  "total_time_on_site" VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  "date_t" DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ASC )
) IN "system";

id,manual_number,user_id,session_id,total_time_on_site,date_t
3,38001,1357,'123','**3h27m42s**','2014-10-02'
4,38001,1357,'123','**2h20m42s**','2014-10-02'
```

I want to do this:

```
select manual_number,user_id,session_id, sum(total_time_on_site)  
FROM "DBA"."TIME_SPENT_DATA" group by manual_number,user_id,session_id
```

I know I cannot do this since total_time_on_site is a varchar. But how can I achieve this?
I want to add those values( and if i have 25h - I need to display 1d 1h)

Can I do this? Thank you

Comment: My $0.02: Pull it off into some code, run it through a regex, parse out your numbers, funnel the junk into a log file, then put it back in the database in a usable format (for example total number of seconds stored as an integer). Then sum away.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm gonna do :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might be better off doing the conversion outside the server, I couldn't resist the fiddling with your data and if you do want to do it in the database some flexible use of substring, charindex and casts should work. Not 100% it's free of errors, but it did work for your rather limited test data.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0d02/1)

```
SELECT 
    manual_number, user_id, session_id,
    CAST(DATEADD(second,SUM(
       CAST(SUBSTRING(total_time_on_site, PATINDEX('%[0-60]%', total_time_on_site), CHARINDEX('h',total_time_on_site)-CHARINDEX('*',total_time_on_site,2)-1) AS INT)*60*60+
       CAST(SUBSTRING(total_time_on_site, CHARINDEX('h',total_time_on_site,0)+1, CHARINDEX('m',total_time_on_site)-CHARINDEX('h',total_time_on_site,0)-1) AS INT)*60+
       CAST(SUBSTRING(total_time_on_site, CHARINDEX('m',total_time_on_site,0)+1, CHARINDEX('s',total_time_on_site)-CHARINDEX('m',total_time_on_site,0)-1) AS INT) 
       ),0)
    AS TIME) AS sum_of_total_time_on_site_as_time
FROM TIME_SPENT_DATA 
GROUP BY manual_number, user_id, session_id
```

Output:

```
manual_number user_id     session_id sum_of_total_time_on_site_as_time
------------- ----------- ---------- ---------------------------------
38001         1357        123        05:48:24.0000000
```